# Using .NET Framework 4.x assemblies in .NET 5.0 projects with Entity Framework dependency

Tags: .net, .net-5

I have a third-party .NET assembly from an SDK which targets .NET Framework 4.5.

I've run the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) on the SDK assembly, and it reports 97% support on the ".NET Core + Platform Extensions" target.

The missing APIs are mostly in `System.Data.EntityClient`, `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses`, `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`, and `System.ServiceModel`. I'm not tremendously familiar with any of these namespaces, but it looks like they belong to the pre-Core version of Entity Framework and WCF.

Is it possible for this third-party assembly to be reliably used in a project targeting .NET 5.0? If so, what do I need to do, to add support for these last missing APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are no shims for those namespaces in .NET 5.0.